# C# Regex match and wrap multiple lines

Tags: c#, regex

I need to make such text, as example

```
Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow sees 40 million visitors each month

|| <b>ID</b> || <b>Column1</b> || <b>Column2</b> ||
| | | |

Stack Overflow Documentation, the largest content expansion since Q&A, launches in July

|| <b>Name</b> || <u>Surname</u> || <u>DoB</u> ||
| | | |

The Developer Story launches in October, giving developers a better way to present their skills
```

look like that

```
    Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow sees 40 million visitors each month

<span>|| <b>ID</b> || <b>Column1</b> || <b>Column2</b> ||
| | | |</span>

Stack Overflow Documentation, the largest content expansion since Q&A, launches in July

<span>|| <b>Name</b> || <u>Surname</u> || <u>DoB</u> ||
| | | |
| | | |
</span>

The Developer Story launches in October, giving developers a better way to present their skills
```

If I try such regex

```
(
 (
   (^|\r\n|)+(\|{1,2})
  )
  (
    [\s\S]*
  )
  (\|{1,2}
   ($|\r\n|)+
  )
)
```

But its not what I need, it selecting wrong area, you can see it here https://regex101.com/r/0h7gVV/2

Other attempt was look like that

```
((^|\r\n{2,}|)+(\|{1,2}))(.*)(\|{1,2}(\r\n{2,}|$|)+)
```

But it ended up selecting each line, you can see the example here https://regex101.com/r/qpwdwj/2

How I should change my regex to make it work in right way?

**UPD**

Wiktor Stribiżew (thanks to him) in comments told me to try his example, it works good for example above but not for all possilbe cases (example here https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/3)

*So-called* tables can look like that

```
|| A | B |
|| c | d |
```

Or that

```
| a | b | c |
| d | e | f |
```

**UPD2**

That's close one https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/7 but it has ugly empty space

**UPD3**

This one is close ( https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/8 ), but for this test text

```
Stack Overflow Documentation, the largest content expansion since Q&A, launches in July

|| <b>Name</b> || <u>Surname</u> || <u>DoB</u> ||
| | | |


||


| a | b | c | u |

The Developer Story launches in October, giving developers a better way to present their skills

| a | b | c |
| d | e | f |
```

It goes like that

```
Stack Overflow Documentation, the largest content expansion since Q&A, launches in July
<span>
|| <b>Name</b> || <u>Surname</u> || <u>DoB</u> ||
| | | |

<!-- not suppose to be wraped up -->
</span><span>||


| a | b | c | u |

</span>The Developer Story launches in October, giving developers a better way to present their skills
<span>
| a | b | c |
| d | e | f |</span>
```

When I am not want to wrap single `||` apperance within line (it suppose to be ignored in this case)

Screenshot for more example
[image]

P.S.

This, let's say, markup below

```
|| <b>ID</b> || <b>Column1</b> || <b>Column2</b> ||
| | | |
```

Will be parsed to html to look like table, where `|| Cell ||` is stands for header and `| cell |` stands for regular cell

So, after parsing it gonna be look like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, your expected output does not seem OK, do you need to duplicate `| | | |`? Try [`Regex.Replace(s, @"(?s)\|{2}.*?\|{2}(?:\s*\|)+", "<span>$&</span>")`](https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/1)

Comment: Yeah, its like rows w empty cells

Comment: @DanilGholtsman what does that mean actually "Yeah, its like rows w empty cells"  ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i'll update question to explain that

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew cool, it works, I updated it  https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/2 (because of it's could start or end with `||` as well as with `|`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why dont you post it as an answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oops it's not always works, all possible cases here https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/3

Comment: Your question is unclear, sorry.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry for that, I tought it dosent really matter here if I put `{1,2}` in your example, but it turnd out that it's not that easy

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that one clsoer but I dont like empty space https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/5

Comment: Does [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/axVXr1/1) work as you expect?

Comment: Well, there are problems w captured spaces and if only one `|` in row

Comment: @DanilGholtsman May you post an example where the regex above does not work?

Comment: @horcrux https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/8

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Sorry but I cannot see what's wrong. Which line do you refer to?

Comment: @horcrux look at my last update in question. If string starts like `||` or `|` and then, no matter whate goes after but if it's not closed by `|` or `||` then it's not suppose to be sleceted

Comment: @horcrux I even added the screenshot

Comment: @DanilGholtsman What about [https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/10](https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/10)

Comment: @horcrux it's awesome! post as an answer, please! (and, if you want to, with explanation what is happening there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is

```
(\|\|?([^|\n\r]+\|\|?)+($|[\r\n]+))+
```

The matching group is `$0` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/12)).

It works as follows:

```
(
  \|\|?         #the line starts with one or two pipes
  (
    [^|\n\r]+   #followed by at least one non-pipe characther
    \|\|?       #and the cell endt with one or two pipes
  )+            #at least one cell, otherwise even the line "||" would be matched
  (
    $           #the text ends (you are NOT in multiline mode) 
  |
    [\r\n]+     #or [\r\n] characters are matched (at least one, otherwise would match even "||A|B"), in order to match also the possible following line
  )
)+              #at least one line
```

If you don't want to match spaces/new lines after the "table", just use an a-few-harder regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/PvPsxF/13)):

```
\|\|?([^|\n\r]+\|\|?)+$([\r\n]+\|\|?([^|\n\r]+\|\|?)+$)*
```

In this last regex remember to use the `m` flag.